# How do I convert long string into JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert a string to a JSON object that gets returned from a Learning Management System. Once the string is a JSON Object I'm going to use it as part of a jQuery plugin I am writing. Here is what I have so far:

**callback to convert:** (I do not have access to the server-side code (it resides on an LMS (AICC), I just access it via javascript and the callback is below, so I am stuck with this text. I do believe after each line there is \n, but this is the exact format I receive .... nothing but text.)

```
ERROR=0
ERROR_TEXT=Successful
VERSION=2.2
AICC_DATA=[CORE]
STUDENT_ID=01234567
STUDENT_NAME=Doe, John R
SCORE=83
TIME=02:35:37
CREDIT=C
LESSON_LOCATION=page_1               
LESSON_STATUS=INCOMPLETE
[Core_Lesson]
[Objectives_Status]
```

The is what I am looking to convert it to:

```
{'ERROR':'0','ERROR_TEXT':'Successful','VERSION':'2.2','AICC_DATA':'[CORE]','STUDENT_ID':'01234567','STUDENT_NAME':'Doe, John R','SCORE':'83','TIME':'02:35:37','CREDIT':'C','LESSON_LOCATION':'page_1','LESSON_STATUS':'INCOMPLETE'}
```

Here is the jQuery I am using: (as you can see I am trying to do this without a loop if possible :)

```
$.get(_url,{command:"GetParam",version:"2.2",session_id:_sid},function(response)
{
    /* this is my attempt at using a RegExp */
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + urlVar + '=([^&]*)').exec(response); 
    /* I thought maybe I could do it using an eval(), but I get an error -> Expected "]" */
    var t = eval('{['+response+']}');                       
});
```

I am confident that I could figure this out using a loop, but I really would like to get this working without the for loop. Is this even possibible? Thanks!

Comment: That stuff is too far from JavaScript syntax to simply `eval()` it like that. You'll have to actually parse it. If you want to avoid a `for` loop for some reason, you can split the input into an array and then use `.forEach()` :-)

Comment: @ Pointy - Maybe a loop is my only option, the reason behind not using a for loop is since I am creating a jQuery plugin I didnt want the loop to slow anything down. Maybe it won't make any difference, but the fastest possible conversion is what I wanted to achieve :)

Comment: I am not too versed with RegExp(), would something like that be faster than a for loop?

Comment: Of course, a RegExp is using at least on for loop internally, so I don't know what performance savings you might get. As always, time it before optimizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your lines do end in "\n" then you could try this:

```
var obj = {};
theTextYouGetFromTheServer.replace(/([^=]+)=(.*)\n/g, function(_, name, value) {
  obj[name] = value;
});
```

If your names can contain "=" of course that'd be a problem.

What that does is match the basic format of your name/value lines (NAME=VALUE) and builds an object. The JavaScript `.replace()` method for strings calls that function repeatedly for each successive match, with the parameters being the entire match (which here we don't care about), and then each matched group (things in parens in the regex).

Comment: +1 I like this answer better than mine, although it will run as if it were a loop (the function will be called once for each match found).

Comment: Thank you both for your time and effort, I am trying this code now. I will return with results shortly.

Comment: Pointy for 2012 - That code is so sexy, very good job and thank you. Works exactly how I envisioned it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = "ERROR=0\nERROR_TEXT=Successful\nVERSION=2.2\nAICC_DATA=[CORE]\nSTUDENT_ID=01234567\nSTUDENT_NAME=Doe, John R\nSCORE=83\nTIME=02:35:37\nCREDIT=C\nLESSON_LOCATION=page_1               \nLESSON_STATUS=INCOMPLETE";

eval('var object = {' + text.replace(/([^=\n]+)=([^\n]+)/g, '"$1":"$2",').replace(/\n/g, "") + '}');

alert(object.SCORE);
```

This doesn't work if you have the last two lines though (`[Core_Lesson]` and `[Objectives_Status]`).

Comment: Also problems if the values might already have some quote characters in them.

Comment: it leaves a , at the end "LESSON_STATUS":"INCOMPLETE",} - You probably need to slice it after replace. .replace(/([^=\n]+)=([^\n]+)/g, '"$1":"$2",').replace(/\n/g, "").slice(0, -1)

Comment: I tried it and the extra comma didn't seem to do any harm. The quote character is a problem.

Comment: But, if the original string doesn't have any quotes, and you are sure it's the right format (i.e. no lines without an equals sign), I think this is the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my version. Please feel free to correct me if it is not good.

```
function toJSON (str) {
     return  '{\'' + str.replace(/=/g, "':'").replace(/\n/g, "','") + '\'}';
}
```